# Multi variable for loop python

Tags: python, for-loop

I know that you can do nested for loops, for example:

```
for ch in a:
    for ch2 in ch:
        print(ch2)
```

However, I've seen for loops that go like this:

```
for ch, ch2 in a:
    # blah blah
```

Are these two loops equivalent? Or does the second loop do something different than the first?

Comment: They are not same.The first loop will gives a product of your iterable's items since the second one is just a multi-assignment loop which iterates over iterable `a` only works if `a` has duplex items.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, they are not.

The second is an example of [multiple assignment](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#assignment-statements). If you assign to a tuple, Python unpacks the values of an iterable into the names you gave.

The second loop is rather equivalent to this:

```
for seq in a:
    ch = seq[0]
    ch2 = seq[1]
    # blah blah
```

As @Kasramvd points out in a comment to your question, this only works if `a` is a sequence with the correct number of items. Otherwise, Python will raise a `ValueError`.

---

Edit to address `dict` iteration (as brought up in comment):

When you iterate over a Python `dict` using the normal `for x in y` syntax, `x` is the *key* relevant to each iteration.

```
for x in y:   # y is a dict
    y[x]      # this retrieves the value because x has the key
```

The type of loop you are talking about is achieved as follows:

```
for key, val in y.items():
    print(key, 'is the key')
    print('y[key] is', val)
```

This is still the same kind of unpacking as described above, because `dict.items` gives you a *list of tuples* corresponding to the `dict` contents. That is:

```
d = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
print(d.items())    # [('a', 1), ('b', 2)]
```

Comment: So when you do a loop, does ch go forwards from seq[0] onwards while seq[1] moves onwards from [1] ? I'm working with a dictionary here and so I'm a tad confused on the interaction of unpacking; would having two assigned variables here present the key and its value?

Comment: @Hackxx Updated my answer to address `dict` iteration and how the above notion fits into it.

Comment: OHHH okay so because dict.items unpacks into a duplex element tuple, the multiple assignment targets the 0th and 1st element right?

Comment: @Hackxx Yes, precisely. If you were to iterate like `for x in y.items()`, `x` would be a _tuple_ each time, but since you provide two assignment targets, Python realizes and unpacks it for you so you have the individual elements.

Comment: I see!! So if you were to (for some unknown reason) use the for x in y.items() loop, you would have to un-tuple everything in the end assuming you want the individual element?

Comment: @Hackxx Yep. You could either access the key as `x[0]` and the value as `x[1]`, or do the multiple assignment unpack on a later line within the loop: `key, val = x`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87041/discussion-between-hackxx-and-two-bit-alchemist).